# Fail during installation of Pillow (Python module) in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install Pillow (Python module) using pip, but it throws this error:

```
ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting
```

So as the error says, I tried:

```
pip install pillow --global-option="--disable-jpeg"
```

But it fails with:

```
error: option --disable-jpeg not recognized
```

Any hints how to deal with it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Thank you @mfitzp. In my case (CentOS) these libs are not available in the yum repo, but actually the solution was even easier. What I did:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
sudo yum install zlib-devel
sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo-devel
```

And now pillow's installation finishes successfully.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me although I didn't need the python-devel

Comment: Worked for me too, just needed to install the libjpeg-turbo-devel package!

Comment: Worked on CentOS 7 like a charm!

Comment: This python-devel was not required on amazon linux yum machine. I think the last one libjpeg-turbo-devel was the missing package.

Answer (score 351):

There is a bug reported for Pillow [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1457), which indicates that `libjpeg` and `zlib` are now [required](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1412) as of Pillow 3.0.0.

The [installation instructions](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/installation.html#linux-installation) for Pillow on Linux give advice of how to install these packages. Note that not all of the following packages may be missing on your machine (comments suggest that only `libjpeg8-dev` is actually missing).

### pip / PyPi (Pillow>3.4.2)

The [latest releases](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) of Pillow are available on PyPi as [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) — the new standard packaging mechanism for Python. These prebuilt packages include all neccessary binary dependencies to allow Pillow to run and should be used if you want to install Pillow using PyPi

To use wheels, you need to have a version of `pip>=1.4`. If you are using an earlier version (`pip --version`) upgrade pip using the following:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Once `pip` is upgraded, `pip install` will use platform-specific wheel files by default if they are available. Use the following command to upgrade Pillow to the latest version available on PyPi:

```
pip install --upgrade pillow
```

### Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or  Raspian Wheezy 7.0

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk
```

### Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff5-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev python-tk
```

### Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt install libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev
```

### Fedora 20

The Fedora 20 equivalent of `libjpeg8-dev` is `libjpeg-devel`.

```
sudo yum install libtiff-devel libjpeg-devel libzip-devel freetype-devel lcms2-devel libwebp-devel tcl-devel tk-devel
```

### Mac OS X (via Homebrew)

On Mac OS X with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) this can be fixed using:

```
brew install libjpeg zlib
```

You may also need to force-link zlib using the following:

```
brew link zlib --force
```

**Update April 2019:** In Mojave the above will not work and you need to run the following [as taken from this bug report on Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438#issuecomment-435169249)

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

**Update July 2016:** There is no longer a formula for `zlib` available in the main repository (Homebrew will prompt you to install `lzlib` which is a different library and will not solve this problem).

There *is* a formula available in the *dupes* repository. You can either tap this repository, and install as normal:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install zlib
```

Or you can install `zlib` via `xcode` instead, as follows:

```
xcode-select --install
```

*Thanks to phoenix, Panos Angelopoulou, nelsonvarela, benjaminz and Kal in the comments*

After these are installed the pip installation of Pillow should work normally.

Comment: Just `libjpeg8-dev` might be fine.

Comment: I was facing the same problem for Mac OS X. I solve it executing 
`brew install libjpeg` 
`brew install zlib`

Comment: Better install libjpeg-dev - with no '8', then also found that zlib1g-dev was missing too.  After: `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev` the pip Pillow install worked on Mint 17.1 (= Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

Comment: I had to force link zlib: `brew link zlib --force`

Comment: @nelsonvarela thank you so much for saying that. I've been trying to fix this for a week and tried everything. `brew link zlib --force` is what did it!

Comment: El Capitan, Python 3.5.1: `brew install libjpeg` fixed it

Comment: what about ubuntu 1604

Comment: `apk add jpeg-dev` for alpine

Comment: `sudo apt install libjpeg8-dev` worked for me, ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Starting with recent Homebrews, `brew link zlib` will not work. macOS Mojave also doesn't seem to install Zlib header with `xcode`, so see [this issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3438#issuecomment-435169249) for a work-around.

Answer (score 36):

On Raspberry pi II, I had the same problem. After trying the following, I solved the problem. The solution is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev worked for Ubuntu 14 also ):

Answer (score 14):

The quickest fix is upgrate the pip. Did worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: worked for me.
Pip install Pillow
(if not working clear cache by pip install --upgrade pip)
Then run again 
Pip install Pillow

Comment: This also worked for me. I have Python 2.6.6 and 3.5.1 on a CentOS VM, and ran `pip3.5 install --upgrade pip3.5`. After that, `pip3.5 install pillow` ran without any issues, and maintained the integrity of the Python2 and Python3 installations.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me to solve jpeg and zlib error :

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip3 install pillow --global-option="build_e
xt" --global-option="--disable-zlib" --global-option="--disable-jpeg"
```

Comment: I needed to install Pillow on an environment where I don't have root access - this is the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me.

```
   `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`
```

Answer (score 10):

```
brew install zlib
```

on OS X doesn't work anymore and instead prompts to install `lzlib`. Installing that doesn't help.

Instead you install XCode Command line tools and that should install `zlib`

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I had the `ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib` but upgrading pip from 7.x to 8.y resolved the problem.

So I would try to update tools before anything else.

That can be done using:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 2):

The alternative, if you don't want to install libjpeg:

```
CFLAGS="--disable-jpeg" pip install pillow
```

From https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/installation.html#external-libraries

Answer (score 2):

Working successfuly :

```
 sudo apt install libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 2):

Anyone with Python 3.9 you can only install Pillow 8.0, Any version lower than that wouldn't work. For more check [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html).

So you can run it like this:

```sh
pip install Pillow==8.0.0
```

BTW this is tested on `pip 21.0.1 (python 3.9)` on MacOS Big Sur 11.2

Comment: Savior ! shukraaan .

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install pillow
```

If it doesn't work, try clearing the

```
cache by pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then again run

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score -3):

On debian / ubuntu you only need:
libjpeg62-turbo-dev

So a simple `sudo apt install libjpeg62-turbo-dev`
and a `pip install pillow`