# Python Pillow not installing under OSX

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, python-imaging-library

I am trying to install the Python Pillow library and I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting
```

I followed the thread to try to fix it: [Fail during installation of Pillow (Python module) in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux)

The problem is that it seems to still not be able to find zlib, which I installed via homebrew.

I did a check to see if it was installed:

```
> brew search zlib
homebrew/dupes/zlib ✔                                        lzlib
```

I noticed it is in a different location than a standard brew install ("homebrew/dupes/zlib").  I tried to do an uninstall/reinstall and it puts it back in the same place ("homebrew/dupes/zlib").  The problem seems to be the installer/compiler just can't find it in that location.

My question is, Is there a way to either alias the lib path, point the installer to this lib location or clear it out completely from home-brew to re-install it clean just as zlib?  What is the best route to take on this?

Thanks,
RB

Comment: How exactly are you installing it? You should be using `pip install pillow`

Answer (score 17):

I figured out how to handle this.  I had to set the following flag, via an environment variable, ahead of the pip install to make sure it used the correct zlib path when compiling pillow.

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include" pip install pillow
```

This worked.

Comment: Works. thanks. Surprised, why its not already in the include path.

Comment: Thank you. you saved my time.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same situation (Homebrew zlib in /usr/local/opt/zlib) but setting `CFLAGS=…` didn't fix the error.

`xcode-select --install` worked.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget to do this after OS upgrades. :)

Comment: Worked on OSX Sierra 10.12.2 - Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I simply installed the jpeg lib in MacOSX Yosemite

brew install jpeg

Thereafter

pip install pillow

This worked nicely! ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are on MacOSX and installed zlib with brew, then try

```
brew link zlib --force
```

It worked for me
Link: [Fail during installation of Pillow (Python module) in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions given so far worked for me (OS X ElCapitan). Here is what worked:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install zlib
brew install jpeg
```

The problem is zlib is not available in default Homebrew anymore. The lzlib that it prompts you to install instead does not work.

You can find detailed answer here: [Fail during installation of Pillow (Python module) in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux)