# ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting

Tags: python, server, ubuntu-12.04, python-imaging-library, reddit

I try to install reddit on a 12.04 ubuntu server but I get an error

Please see the lines from terminal below. Please help me to fix it.
I get this error after the ff line "**sudo python setup.py develop**"

I already install the all necessary dependencies using the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~reddit/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
Cannot find Cython. Skipping Cython build.
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running develop
Checking .pth file support in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
/usr/bin/python -E -c pass
TEST PASSED: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ appears to support .pth files
running egg_info
writing requirements to r2.egg-info/requires.txt
writing r2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to r2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to r2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to r2.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'r2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'r2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Cfilters.so -> 
Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/r2.egg-link (link to .)
r2 0.0.0dev is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /home/reddit/reddit/r2
Processing dependencies for r2==0.0.0dev
Searching for Pillow
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/Pillow/
Best match: Pillow 3.2.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/e2/af/0a3981fffc5cd43078eb8b1057702e0dd2d5771e5aaa36cbd140e32f8473/Pillow-3.2.0.tar.gz#md5=7cfd093c11205d9e2ebe3c51dfcad510
Processing Pillow-3.2.0.tar.gz
Running Pillow-3.2.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-72k68O/Pillow-3.2.0/egg-dist-tmp-auWCL6
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_static'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.landscape.yaml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'build_children.sh'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 138, in <module>
    """,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 27, in run
    self.install_for_development()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 105, in install_for_development
    self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 692, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 821, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 833, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 608, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 638, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 828, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1105, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1094, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 30, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 72, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 32, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 767, in <module>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 179, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 166, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 20, in run
    self.build()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "setup.py", line 512, in build_extensions

ValueError: jpeg is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-jpeg, aborting
```

Comment: have you tried using the `--disable-jpeg` flag?

Comment: related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux/34631976

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may need some additional libraries to use Pillow. For Ubuntu 12.04 you can try the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34631976/2821252)

```
sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk
```

This previous solution suggests just trying to install `libjpeg8-dev` first.

Comment: After that I get a new error, Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 319, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed

Comment: I try to do it again and now I get a different error:
Installed /home/reddit/reddit/r2
Processing dependencies for r2==0.0.0dev
Searching for l2cs>=2.0.2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/l2cs/
No local packages or download links found for l2cs>=2.0.2
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('l2cs>=2.0.2')

Comment: l2cs looks like a deprecated library. You can try to manually install it from https://github.com/kemitche/l2cs but it looks like it's been removed from pypi

Comment: how I can install this module ?

Comment: "Run setup.py install to install the module" is the all instruction for this module and I don't know how to install it. I know to install stuff just using "apt-get". Some help very welcomed.

Comment: Download the zip from github, extract it, navigate into the folder and run `python install setup.py`. You may need to install the python module `ez_setup` using pip as well. Please mark this question as answered and open a separate one for further questions because this is quite off track.

Comment: Just used in Ubuntu 18.04 to solve the same error. Had to replace `libtiff4-dev` with `libtiff5-dev`, but it worked.