# Getting error "Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL."

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner to machine learning, so I was trying to create a model for recognizing images referenced from Keras blog. I have installed Anaconda 3 on windows 10 and all the packages like tensorflow, keras, scipy, numpy, pandas

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')
    img = load_img('E:/ML_R&D/training_set/cats/cat.3919.jpg') # this Line is giving me error
```

I am using conda command and pillow using pip, but when I run a code taken from keras blog I got the error.

Comment: please indicate *where exactly* in your code the error pops up

Comment: these lines which are giving error***********      
img = load_img('E:\\ML_R&D\\cat.jpg')  # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (300, 300, 3)

Comment: 1) there cannot be *two* lines generating the error 2) please indicate the exact position *in the code* 3) if indeed the error happens so early in your program, do everyone here a favor and **remove** the rest of your code, which is irrelevant & useless for the question 4) include explicitly all your imports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the issue is solved, may be the problem was that I did not restarted my system after adding all the libraries. This issue can be closed.

Answer (score 7):

You will want to install the PIL package.

[How do I install PIL/Pillow for Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179948/how-do-i-install-pil-pillow-for-python-3-6)

```
pip install pillow
```

or

```
pip3 install pillow
```

Comment: I have pillow installed

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Firstly make sure that the PIL is uninstalled as PIL and pillow cannot co-exist. For this open Anaconda Powershell Prompt and type
`pip uninstall pillow`
Then press y(yes) when asked.
If you do not have pillow or PIL then proceed to step 2

Step 2: In the same powershell prompt, execute
`pip install pillow`

Step 3: After the installation, close the jupyter notebook, anaconda, and restart your system.

Step 4: Now execute
`from keras.preprocessing.image import load_image` .
IT WILL WORK !!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import the library. Use "import PIL"