# Set Python path environment variable

Tags: python

I have a problem with my Python program. While running this program on an IDE (spyder IDE) I obtain no error and it works perfectly. Otherwise, if I run it in the python IDLE I obtain the following error.

```
 RESTART: C:\Users\jeane\Documents\Cours\BSP sem2\TechnicalPart\CNNLuminosity\Serverside\finalCnnOutput.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeane\Documents\Cours\BSP sem2\TechnicalPart\CNNLuminosity\Serverside\finalCnnOutput.py", line 43, in <module>
    test_image = image.load_img('blab-cam' + str(i) + '-snapshots/gallery-images/latest.png', target_size = (64,64))
  File "C:\Users\jeane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 108, in load_img
    raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `load_img` requires PIL.
```

I think this error has to something with the Python path environment variable since I can't find the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the [Pil](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) module.It has nothing to do with the python path.

> PIL is deprecated, and pillow is the successor.
>
> pip install pillow

[For More](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39179948/12210002)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the environment as below if you are not specific to the versions

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow keras numpy pandas sklearn pillow
```

But if you are specific to versions then

```
pip install pillow
```

Note: If only install pillow then you need deactivate and reactivate the virtual environment.