# How to install PIL in Pycharm with Python 3?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I can't get PIL to work on pycharm. It should work after installing Pillow / Pillow-PIL libraries but it doesn't.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: While it won't fix your problem, please avoid naming your modules after [builtin modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using ``Pillow-PIL``? It is seven years old and doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: `Pillow` on its own didnt work. So I tried `Pillow-PIL` which also doesnt work.

Comment: Do by any chance you have multiple versions of python installed in your computer? A common problem is when we install modules on one version and our IDE is configured to another.

Comment: I have installed `python 3.7` on my computer. Both `IDLE` and `Pycharm` use `python 3.7`

Answer (score 0):

This question is apparently the same than this other issue:

[How do I install PIL/Pillow for Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179948/how-do-i-install-pil-pillow-for-python-3-6)

`pip install pillow`  should be the answer

Else, you can try Anaconda, it is already installed by default.
But this does not explain your issue.