# "The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg" installing Pillow on Alpine Linux

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-imaging-library, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run Python's Scrapy in a Docker container based on [python:alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/). It was working before, but now I'd like to use Scrapy's [Image Pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline) which requires me to install Pillow.

As a simplified example, I tried the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev curl
RUN apk add libjpeg zlib tiff freetype lcms libwebp tcl openjpeg
RUN pip install Pillow
```

However, when I try to build this I get an error which contains the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ft5yzzuv/Pillow/setup.py", line 744, in <module>
    zip_safe=not debug_build(), )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ft5yzzuv/Pillow/setup.py", line 545, in build_extensions
    raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-ft5yzzuv/Pillow/setup.py", line 756, in <module>
    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

I went through the requirements on https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html and tried to find the corresponding packages for Alpine, although one I couldn't find was **libimagequant**, so this might be the 'culprit'. Nonetheless, it the traceback and error message seem to be saying that `jpeg` is missing, whereas I have installed `openjpeg`.

How can I modify the `Dockerfile` so that `pip install Pillow` runs?

Comment: just add:
`apk add jpeg-dev`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In a comment that appears to have been deleted later, someone pointed me to https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/c05099f45c0d94a2a98c3609a96bdb6cf7446627/depends/alpine_Dockerfile. Based on that Dockerfile I modified my own as follows:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev curl
RUN apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev
RUN pip install Pillow
```

Now it builds successfully.

Comment: After carefully reading error I noticed part "The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg". Those headers are held in *-dev packages. So I went to https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=libjpeg*&branch=edge and in the end "apk --no-cache --update-cache add libjpeg-turbo-dev zlib-dev" did the trick.

Comment: `apk add jpeg-dev` is all that you need to fix the "The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg" issue

Comment: I got out with less of linux packages:
```FROM python:3.7-alpine
RUN apk --update add gcc libgcc musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
```
Builds faster and fetches less of binaries.

Answer (score 229):

For debian

```
sudo apt install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: `apt-get` does not exist on Alpine Linux, the package manager is `apk`.

Comment: Even in Ubuntu `apt` is now the preferred package manager for end user https://askubuntu.com/a/446484

Comment: I only had to install `libjpeg-dev` on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I used this answer on Raspberry Pi 4b and it worked

Answer (score 38):

For macOS:

```
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
```

Reason:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: This got pillow working for me! Working in Python 3.9 and going through Django 3 by Example Third Edition.

Comment: if different brew prefix then use `arch -arm64 brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2`

Comment: I only needed libjpeg.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this problem with docker image `python:3.6-alpine` I solved it by adding these packages `apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev`.

Comment: This works for using `Pillow` with Docker.

Answer (score 11):

have you seen this QA? [Fail during installation of Pillow (Python module) in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux)

they say you have to update your pip and install libjpeg-dev.

Comment: They don't mention the alpine based solution: `apk add jpeg-dev`

Comment: `sudo dnf install libjpeg-turbo-devel libjpeg-turbo-utils` for Fedora 32

Comment: libjpeg-turbo-devel worked for redhat7

Answer (score 10):

Just in case anyone else is still struggling like I was you can see the official alpine Dockerfile for Pillow here: https://github.com/python-pillow/docker-images/blob/master/alpine/Dockerfile#L20

It states the following dependencies:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add python3 \

                   ...

                   # Pillow dependencies
                   jpeg-dev \
                   zlib-dev \
                   freetype-dev \
                   lcms2-dev \
                   openjpeg-dev \
                   tiff-dev \
                   tk-dev \
                   tcl-dev \
                   harfbuzz-dev \
                   fribidi-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

**In short**, this helps:

```
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libsqlite3-dev \
  libpng-dev libjpeg-dev
```

---

**Detailed:**

I have the same error with `python:3.8-slim-buster` image. Solution presented by @pierangelo-orizio worked for me, but I just cleaned it to a minimal required packages list. So here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libsqlite3-dev \
    libpng-dev libjpeg-dev

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
VOLUME /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And `requirements.txt`:

```
Django>=2.1,<2.2
wagtail>=2.4,<2.5
django-cors-headers==2.5.3
python-dotenv==0.10.3
```

Answer (score 4):

Run into the same issue on python 3.9. Fixed it by bumping pillow version in `requirements.txt` to `Pillow>=8.0`. There's a nice matrix of which pillow version supports which python version [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For yum users, this should work:

```
sudo yum -y install libjpeg-turbo-devel
pip3 install Pillow
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're missing `libjpeg.so` package in runtime, try this (alpine linux):

```
apk add --no-cache jpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to create a requirements.txt and insert this in Dockerfile:

```
    RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install build-essential g++ flex bison gperf ruby perl \
  mysql-client \
  libsqlite3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libfontconfig1-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6 libssl-dev \
  libpng-dev libjpeg-dev python libx11-dev libxext-dev -y
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD requirements.txt /code/
 COPY . /code
 RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ADD . /code/
```

example of requirements.txt

```
Django==1.9.7
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-filer==1.2.5
django-filter==0.15.0
django-grappelli==2.8.1
django-image-cropping==1.0.3
django-mptt==0.8.6
django-nested-admin==3.0.10
django-nested-inline==0.3.6
django-polymorphic==0.8.1
django-taggit==0.21.2
django-tinymce==2.4.0
dnspython==1.15.0
easy-thumbnails==2.3
enum34==1.1.2
funcsigs==0.4
idna==2.1
ipaddress==1.0.17
mercurial==3.7.3
mock==1.3.0
mysql-python
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.2
parsedatetime==2.1
pbr==1.8.0
Pillow==3.3.1
psutil==3.4.2
pyasn1==0.1.9
PyICU==1.9.2
pyOpenSSL==16.1.0
pyRFC3339==1.0
python-augeas==0.5.0
python-monkey-business==1.0.0
python2-pythondialog==3.3.0
pytz==2014.10
requests==2.11.1
six==1.10.0
Unidecode==0.4.19
urllib3==1.16
zope.component==4.2.2
zope.event==4.2.0
zope.hookable==4.0.4
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

Comment: I suppose there are many excess packages (114Mb!) but it worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding "RUN apk add jpeg-dev" to Dockerfile fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For **macOS** users, just run:

```bash
brew install libjpeg libtiff little-cms2 openjpeg webp
```