# zlib dependency for Pillow fails on ubuntu 18.04 despite required library installed

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, zlib, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to install the `Pillow` package on an Ubuntu 18.04 VPS running Python 3.7. I first created a virtual environment --

```
python -m venv /path/to/env
source /path/to/env/bin/activate
```

from there i tried installing `Pillow` by running `pip install Pillow` but the following exception happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-0c7eruo4/Pillow/setup.py", line 806, in <module>
        raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
    __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

    The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
    a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

    Please see the install instructions at:
       https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631806/fail-during-installation-of-pillow-python-module-in-linux) answer the package `libjpeg8-dev` needs to be installed, but Ubuntu's telling me it's *already* been installed, so I don't know what's going on. (I also verified the non-dev version `libjpeg8` was installed, to be safe) I haven't encountered this many errors when simply setting up a Python development environment before -- can someone advise?