# Problems in installing Pillow

Tags: python, pip

So I'm new to Python 3, version 3.8, and I wanted to install some "requirements" from carykh "jumpcutter". The first one I'm having problem with Pillow. Whenever I want to install him I use the instructions from https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows-installation and/or [Pip can't install pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496599/pip-cant-install-pillow)

The first uses: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow` and it gives me an error in the 
image [FirstCode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHh7C.png)

The second uses `python3 -m pip install Pillow` and it gives me an error in the image [SecondCode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRN5B.png)

Comment: Install it from the command prompt (C:\), not the REPL.

Comment: Type in cmd just `python` and see if that works, then try `python -m pip --version`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:
`python` instead of `python3`

Also ensure that your Python.exe is added to your `PATH` - info [here](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)

Try: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

To upgrade your pip, sometimes this can help.

Comment: No worries @MIghtDarkGames -- Don't forget to accept answers on StackOverflow (:

Comment: `python` typically defaults to Python 2, which has reached end-of-life. Python 3 is not fully backwards compatible with Python 2, so if you want to future-proof your Python-learning experience, use `python3`, not `python`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run shell commands on a Python command line.
Exit the Python command line by typing `exit()` and pressing enter. Then, try the commands again.

BTW, in the future, it's best to just copy and paste your logs into your StackOverflow post instead of taking a screenshot. That way, the logs are searchable by other people who have the same problem. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and the code. :)